# Specify sp_add_schedule (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to do time intervals using the add schedule of Microsoft SQL server 2008. I am being specific and i want the time to run `weekly once sunday midnight`. My `@freq_type` is 8 since its running weekly and the `@freq_subday_type` is 1 since i want it to run at a specific time. However this can also be applied to `daily once midnight`. I dont want it to look the same. How can i make the sunday one to be more specific, specifying that it has to be sunday which is a specific day.

Daily Once Midnight

```
EXEC sp_add_schedule  
    @schedule_name = N'UTC +3h Daily Once Midnight' ,  
    @freq_type = 4,  
    @freq_interval = 1,
    @freq_subday_type = 1 ,
    @freq_subday_interval = 0,
      @active_start_time=210000        
GO
```

Weekly once Sunday midnight

```
EXEC sp_add_schedule  
    @schedule_name = N'UTC +6h Weekly Once Sunday Midnight' ,  
    @freq_type = 8,  
    @freq_interval = 1,
    @freq_subday_type = 1 ,
    @freq_subday_interval = 0,
      @active_start_time=180000        
GO
```

Comment: Are you trying to run job only on sunday every week

Comment: Yes i am @TheGameiswar

Comment: I dont see any  issue with your second schedule ,msdn specifies the same..@freq_type = 8,  
    @freq_interval = 1,  means weekly only sunday

Comment: Yeah @TheGameiswar kind of true but confusing in a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think that the second schedule shall be as follows:**

```
USE msdb ;  
GO 

EXEC sp_add_schedule  
  @schedule_name = N'UTC +6h Weekly Once Sunday Midnight' ,  
  @freq_type = 8,  
  @freq_interval = 1,
  @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
  @freq_subday_type = 1 ,
  @freq_subday_interval = 0,
  @active_start_time=180000        
Go
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks @user6426692, just needed to just add that one and now it runs successfully.